# 502 error from Soundcloud Api

Tags: python, soundcloud

I've recently started working with apis for the first time and am running into trouble with soundcloud's. I'm trying to generate a list of tracks liked by the list of users who liked a particular track. I have the code working separately as get_favtracks and get_idlist, but when I run trackfavtracks I get a 502 error from the server.

Here's the code:

```
import soundcloud
#gets a list of favorited track ids for a given user id
#only returns IDs for tracks that are accessible to API
def get_favtracks(uid):
    tracklist = []
    client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='f3b669e6e4509690939aed943c56dc99')
    favtracks = client.get('/users/'+str(uid)+'/favorites', order='id',limit=page_size, linked_partitioning=1)
    for track in favtracks.collection:
        tracklist.append(track.id)

    #Same pagination code as get_idlist
    if not hasattr(favtracks, 'next_href'):
        None

    else:

        #if it does have multiple pages, we have to keep querying until we get a favlist object
        #that doesn't have a next_href attribute.
        newlink = favtracks.next_href

        try:
            while full == False:
                newlist = client.get(newlink)
                #for each page we get we add all the id's to the idlist
                for track in newlist.collection:
                    tracklist.append(track.id)
                if not hasattr(favtracks, 'next_href'):
                    full == True
                else:
                    newlink = newlist.next_href
        except AttributeError:
            None
    return tracklist


#Gets the id list of likers of a given track url
def get_idlist(page):
    idlist = []
    #create the client with the clientID
    client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='f3b669e6e4509690939aed943c56dc99')
    #get a track object from soundcloud using /resolve and by sending them a track url
    track = client.get('/resolve', url=page)
    #get a user object from soundcloud using the user_id attribute of the track object that we just got
    user = client.get('/users/'+str(track.user_id))

    #Print the username and title of the track
    print(user.username)
    print(track.title)

    #get the first list of likers of the track id, set the limit the the page_size variable(defined above), idk what order does
    favlist = client.get('/tracks/'+str(track.id)+'/favoriters', order='id',limit=page_size, linked_partitioning=1)



    #add each user id from the favlist to the idlst
    for user in favlist.collection:
        idlist.append(user.id)

    #if the track favlist object given to us by soundcloud has the next_href attribute
    #it means it has multiple pages. If it doesn't have multiple pages we're done
    if not hasattr(favlist, 'next_href'):
        None

    else:

        #if it does have multiple pages, we have to keep querying until we get a favlist object
        #that doesn't have a next_href attribute.
        newlink = favlist.next_href

        try:
            while full == False:
                newlist = client.get(newlink)
                #for each page we get we add all the id's to the idlist
                for user in newlist.collection:
                    idlist.append(user.id)
                if not hasattr(favlist, 'next_href'):
                    full == True
                else:
                    newlink = newlist.next_href
        except AttributeError:
            None
    return idlist



#define the page_size variable, which is a max 200 (set by SC), and determines how many
#results are one the pages that soundcloud is returning.
#You don't HAVE to define a page_size variable, you can just put in 200. but the tut did this
page_size = 200
full = False

url1 = 'https://soundcloud.com/imnaut/bad-gal-naut-bootleg'
uid1 = 10646255
#total likes = 2

url2 = 'https://soundcloud.com/etherealfamily/capt-pizza-faded'
#https://soundcloud.com/pr0j3c7alpha
uid2 = 17933002

url3 = 'https://soundcloud.com/michael_mason/let-it-fall'
uid3 = 31531684
#total likes = 657

#create a list of data to test on stuff later
url4 = 'https://soundcloud.com/ragelogic/why-dont-we-talk-anymore'
uid4 = 6523547
#total likes = 7916

url5 = 'https://soundcloud.com/zomboy/miles-away-ft-nefera'
uid5 = 2323997
#total likes = 25711







#takes a track url and returns the combined list of likes for every person that liked that song
def trackfavtracks(page):
    dictoftracks = {}
    client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='f3b669e6e4509690939aed943c56dc99')
    listofids = get_idlist(page)
    for id1 in listofids:
        listoftracks = get_favtracks(id1)
        for id2 in listoftracks:
            if id2 not in dictoftracks.keys():
                dictoftracks[id2] = 1
            if id2 in dictoftracks.keys():
                dictoftracks[id2] += 1
    return dictoftracks





#print(len(get_idlist(url2)))
#print(len(get_favtracks(uid2)))
print(len(trackfavtracks(url2)))
print("Done")
```